# How to do form validation and posting the form data to the server in the same script on the click of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate form fields like, Name (must not be blank), Email_id(must be valid), Mobile(Must be valid). After the validating the info I have to post the form data to sever. I am try to validate form data then post info to the server on on single click of button.

**my form.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="register-form" >
    <div class="col-lg-8">      
        <div class="fieldgroup">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="userName">Name:<font
                style="color: red;">*</font></label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <input style=" height: 30px;" class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName"
                    placeholder="Full Name" value="" type="text" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fieldgroup">
            <label for="email" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:<font
                style="color: red;">*</font></label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <input style="height: 30px;" class="form-control" name="email"
                    id="email" placeholder="you@example.com" value=""
                    type="text" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fieldgroup">
            <label for="userContactNumber" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Mobile:<font
                style="color: red;">*</font></label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <input style="height: 30px; width:100%;" class="form-control" id="userContactNumber"
                    name="userContactNumber" placeholder="Mobile Number"
                    onkeypress="enableKeys(event);" maxlength="10" type="text" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fieldgroup marg-bot-45">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-info" id="btnBooking">Confirm
                        Booking&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                    </a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"
                        onclick="javascript:clearAddress();">
                        Clear&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
        </div> 
    </div>                                  
</form>
```

**script for validating form**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($,W,D)
        {
            var JQUERY4U = {};
            JQUERY4U.UTIL =
            {
                setupFormValidation: function()
                {
                    //form validation rules
                    $("#register-form").validate({
                        rules: {
                            userName: "required",                           
                            email: {
                                required: true,
                                email: true
                            },                                              
                            userContactNumber: "required"                       

                        },
                        messages: {
                            userName: "Please enter your Name",
                            userContactNumber: "Please enter your Mobile number",                           
                            email: "Please enter a valid email address",                                            

                        },
                        submitHandler: function(form) {
                            form.submit();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
            $(D).ready(function($) {
                JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
            });
            })(jQuery, window, document);
    </script>
```

**Script for posting the form data**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnBooking").on("click", function(e){

        // as you have used hyperlink(a tag), this prevent to redirect to another/same page
        e.preventDefault();

        // get values from textboxs 
        var uName = $('#userName').val();
        var mailId = $('#addressemailId').val();
        var mobNum = $('#userContactNumber').val();

        $.ajax({
        url:"http://192.168.1.11/services/bookService4Homes.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{type:"booking",Name:uName, Email:mailId, Mob_Num:mobNum },
        //type: should be same in server code, otherwise code will not run
        ContentType:"application/json",
        success: function(response){
        //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error: function(err){
        //alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
        })
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please do not post the same question more than once.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap `if($("#register-form").valid()){}` around your ajax to only submit the form if it passes validation.

```
if($("#register-form").valid()){
     $.ajax({
        url:"http://192.168.1.11/services/bookService4Homes.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{type:"booking",Name:uName, Email:mailId, Mob_Num:mobNum },
        //type: should be same in server code, otherwise code will not run
        ContentType:"application/json",
        success: function(response){
            //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error: function(err){
            //alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, if($("#register-form").valid()); or if($("#register-form").valid()){};

Comment: This is not going to work because the OP's `click` handler is going to interfere with the plugin's `submitHandler`.